# what is wrong with my recursion code?

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, recurrence

I have a recurrence series so i have converted into recursion form.
But it will show as maximum stack size reached.

The same code is **working with n=4** as fn(4) and working correctly but not working with higher values. what is the problem with higher values such as  n = Math.pow(10, 18)

```
var fn = function(n){   

    // take initial value of f(0) = 1 & f(1) = 1
    if(n===1 || n=== 0)     return 1;

    //calculate on basis of initial values
    else if (n === -1)  return (fn(1) - 3* fn(0) - gn(-1) - 2* gn(0));

    else
        return (3*fn(n-1) + 2 * fn(n-2) + 2* gn(n-1) + 3* gn(n-2));
}; 

var gn = function(n){

        // take initial value of g(0) = 1 & g(1) = 1
        if (n === 1 || n === 0) return 1;

        //calculate on basis of initial values
        else if(n === -1) return ((gn(1) - gn(0)) / 2);

        else return (gn(n-1) + 2* gn(n-2));
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with higher values, such as `n = Math.pow(10, 18)` is that the stack is simply not that big. (Not even close.) You can usually have a stack depth of a couple thousand, and not much more.

You should use iteration instead.

Comment: is there any termination issue as well in the above code?

Comment: @AnuragJain Not unless you have negative `n`. Your base cases look taken care of.

Comment: i was actually looking for faster way to solve this problem. can i go with memoization or iteration in my case?

Comment: @AnuragJain I would suggest using both.